# Everybody has me, What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Everybody has me,
>   Everything does too.
>   We need not argue semantics,
>   it’s just my point of view.
>   Everybody has me,
>   Yet no one has me two.
>   Don’t ever, ever forget me,
>   Lest happiness turn blue.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Death / one's end

As,

Everybody has me,

> every living one must die

Everything does too.

> everything dies !

We need not argue semantics,
it’s just my point of view.

> how one dies is not a matter of interest !

Everybody has me,

> Obvious

Yet no one has me two.

> No one can have two deaths !

Don’t ever, ever forget me,
Lest happiness turn blue.

> We are all mortals, a basic fact we forget to dwell in happiness, perhaps it's what meant by!

Comment: What about Energy ? It doesn't fit for energy.

Comment: Little confused. Everybody "has" me implies a "thing". I guess everybody experiences death but "has death"?? May be it is just me.

Comment: @DEEM, perhaps the OP's "it’s just my point of view " should play a role here ... I guess...:-)

Answer (score 3):

is it (not sure though)

> existence/life

explanation

> everybody and everything has existence, no one has two,if you forget about it, (i.e you are dead/ turning blue)

Answer (score 2):

You are

> an **ORIGIN**.

"Everybody has me, Everything does too."

> Every person and thing has an origin. Each thing was created at some time and place.

"We need not argue semantics, it’s just my point of view."

> In mathematics, the [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(mathematics)) is simply a fixed point of reference, which is placed in an arbitrary location to define some Euclidean space. It does not provide much semantic meaning, for example, the distance between two points can be defined in absence of an origin point.

"Everybody has me, Yet no one has me two."

> No person or thing can have two origins. Each person's life begins in only one location, and in only one point in time.

"Don’t ever, ever forget me, Lest happiness turn blue."

> Like the phrase "Don't forget where you came from", people often say that it's unwise to forget one's origins and history. Knowing one's past can help them make better decisions in the future.
>  
>  Also, "Origin" sounds like the word "orange", and according to color theory, orange is considered the complimentary color of blue. And if you receive a compliment, you will feel happy!

Comment: This makes more sense to me than the accepted answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this could be:

> A name

Comment: You can have two names

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, but you always have one main name.

Comment: @Seyed nope. Where I live some people have two main names (always in the same order though)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid, It is definitely exceptional, weird and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's

> smile (laugh,...)

Everybody and everything can have it, it's caused by and shows happines, everyone has very specific sense of humor, if forgotten, one may be sad and you can't really have two.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Characteristics / Personality

Everybody has me,
Everything does too.

> Everything has its own personality/characteristics.

We need not argue semantics,
it’s just my point of view.

> We shouldn't argue about the person's character as everyone has its own perception for each one.

Everybody has me,
Yet no one has me two.

> Every person has a character until unless one is suffering from Multiple Personality Disorder.

Don’t ever, ever forget me,
Lest happiness turn blue.

> One shouldn't try to copy other's characters. Personal with calm (blue color representation) always run happy in life.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> The letter "o" ?

Everybody has me

> There is an "o" in "EverybOdy"

Everything does too.

> "Everything dOes" contain an "o" too

We need not argue semantics,
it’s just my point of view.

> Sure, we don't need to discuss that, we can clearly see these "o"...

Everybody has me,

> Same at the first one.

Yet no one has me two.

> "Yet nO One" have two "o"

Don’t ever, ever forget me,
Lest happiness turn blue.

> I'm not native speaker, so I didn't found this one but I think it could be a word game with an happiness' synonymous losing its "o" to become something "blue".